# How to add a CSS class to a div?

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code from [Railscast #288 Billing with Stripe](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe).

```
if status == 200
  alert(response.id)
else
  $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
  $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

This particular line `$('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)` displays the error message. Since I'm also using Twitter Bootstrap, I would like to add `class="alert alert-error"` to that div. How can I do that?

Comment: Beyond trivial. Did you consider googling 'jquery add class'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by use below code:

```
$('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message).addClass('alert alert-error')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
$('#stripe_error').addClass('alert alert-error');
```